# TF 2.0 guide: documentation error: create custom metric

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I implemented the custom metric shown in this page (CatgoricalTruePositives)
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation

I think it is full of bugs, it has some comments saying (#fix this).
Any way, here what's particularly wrong about it. The accuracy of the NN approaches 99%, yet, this metric says:

```
binary_true_positives: 8459.0000
```

(as shown on the website too).
If number of samples in MNIST is 50,000, then at least 45k of them should be true positives.
What went wrong with their simple example of custom metric?

For sake of completeness, here is their example:

```
class CatgoricalTruePositives(keras.metrics.Metric):

def __init__(self, name='binary_true_positives', **kwargs):
  super(CatgoricalTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
  self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
  y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred)
  values = tf.equal(tf.cast(y_true, 'int32'), tf.cast(y_pred, 'int32'))
  values = tf.cast(values, 'float32')
  if sample_weight is not None:
    sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, 'float32')
    values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
  return self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))  # TODO: fix

def result(self):
  return tf.identity(self.true_positives)  # TODO: fix

def reset_states(self):
  # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
  self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```